Filebeat not updating datastream in elastic search
I have a docker swarm cluster with 3 nodes. I set up a elasticsearch, kibana and filebeat as docker swarm services. These three swarm services are running without an error. A datastream is created by filebeat but no logs are updated in this datastream. Filebeat is deployed as "mode: global".

Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           24.0.7
API version:       1.43

docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"
networks:
 default:
   name: elastic
   external: false
 external:
   external: true
volumes:
 filebeatdata01:
   driver: local

services:
 es01:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
   deploy:
     mode: replicated
     replicas: 1
     restart_policy:
       condition: any
     resources:
       limits:
         cpus: "1"
         memory: 6000M
     placement:
       constraints:
         - node.labels.monitoring01 == true
   ports:
     - target: 9200
       published: 9200
       protocol: TCP
       mode: host
   labels:
     co.elastic.logs/module: elasticsearch
   networks:
     - external
   volumes:
     - /home/ubuntu/elasticsearchnew/esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
   environment:
     - node.name=es01
     - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
     - discovery.type=single-node
     - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
     - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
     - xpack.security.enabled=true
     - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=false
     - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=false
     - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
     - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
   ulimits:
     memlock:
       soft: -1
       hard: -1
 kibana:
   depends_on:
     - es01
   image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
   deploy:
     mode: replicated
     replicas: 1
     restart_policy:
       condition: any
     resources:
       limits:
         cpus: "1"
         memory: 1000M
     placement:
       constraints:
         - node.labels.monitoring01 == true
   ports:
     - target: 5601
       published: 5601
       protocol: TCP
       mode: host
   networks:
     - external
   labels:
     co.elastic.logs/module: kibana
   volumes:
     - /home/ubuntu/elasticsearchnew/kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
   environment:
     - SERVERNAME=kibana
     - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es01:9200
     - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
     - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
     - XPACK_SECURITY_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
     - XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
     - XPACK_REPORTING_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
 filebeat01:
   depends_on:
     - es01
   image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:${STACK_VERSION}
   command: ["setup"]
   deploy:
     mode: global
     resources:
       limits:
         cpus: "0.1"
         memory: 128M
   networks:
     - external
   user: root
   volumes:
     - filebeatdata01:/usr/share/filebeat/data
     - /home/ubuntu/elasticsearchnew/filebeat_ingest_data:/usr/share/filebeat/ingest_data/
     - /home/ubuntu/elasticsearchnew/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro
     - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers:ro
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
   environment:
     - ELASTIC_USER=elastic
     - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
     - output.elasticsearch.hosts=es01:9200

Filebeat.yaml
filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false

filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      hints.enabled: true

processors:
- add_cloud_metadata: ~

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: '${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS:es01:9200}'
  username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME:xxxxxxxx}'
  password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD:xxxxxxxxxxx}'

setup.kibana:
  host: '${KIBANA_HOSTS:kibana:5601}'
  username: '${ELASTIC_USERNAME:xxxxxxx}'
  password: '${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}'


curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v=true&h=index,shard,prirep,state,node,unassigned.reason&s=state&pretty" -u elastic:jokPxRRJFIAjx1UYWNu0 | grep .ds-filebeat-8.14.3-2024
.ds-filebeat-8.14.3-2024.07.30-000001 0 r UNASSIGNED INDEX_CREATED
.ds-filebeat-8.14.3-2024.07.30-000001 0 p STARTED es01

One of the above shards is not allocated because shard with same name is already allocated.
Any idea how to solve this ?
EFK stack version is 8.7. I updated elastic search, kibana and filebeat to version 8.14. I deleted and redeployed the EFK stack.
